# why is sfwcomm1 in "Defined" state after a storage VIO reboot?

Tags: aix

```
root@vio # lsdev -C | grep sfwcomm
sfwcomm0 Available 02-00-02-FF Fibre Channel Storage Framework Comm
sfwcomm1 Defined 02-01-02-FF Fibre Channel Storage Framework Comm
sfwcomm2 Available 00-00-02-FF Fibre Channel Storage Framework Comm
sfwcomm3 Available 00-01-02-FF Fibre Channel Storage Framework Comm
...
```

**Q:** how can we bring it to "Available" again? How to debug the issue?

```
root@vio # fcstat fcs1

Error opening device: /dev/fscsi1
root@vio # lsattr -El fscsi1
attach       switch    How this adapter is CONNECTED         False
dyntrk       yes       Dynamic Tracking of FC Devices        True+
fc_err_recov fast_fail FC Fabric Event Error RECOVERY Policy True+
scsi_id      0x7e1400  Adapter SCSI ID                       False
sw_fc_class  3         FC Class for Fabric                   True
root@vio #
```

According to "lsmap -all -npiv" two LPARs are not logged in to the SAN Fabric because of this, only having redundancy problems.

Comment: is it possible that the HBA failed? check errpt and/or the HMC.

Comment: What do you mean by "storage VIO reboot" - was the storage rebooted, or the VIOS? 
Apart from that, usually you could just "cfgmgr -l sfwcomm1 -v" to get some more details why loading the driver for this fails or "mkdev -l sfwcomm1" which should load the driver in case there would be no further issues, but as this is done during boot this indicates other issues.

Hence, did you contact IBM support about this topic, what was the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root@vio # fcstat fcs1
Error opening device: /dev/fscsi1

-->> it turned out the cable is/was bad. so hw issue.